# Удаление ненужных функций

Tags: java, android

Как очистить мусор в проекте или библиотеке?

Я использую сторонние библиотеки. Оттуда мне нужно только пару функций. А остальные попросту занимают место, память. Как от них избавиться? Может есть программы или придется все ручками удалять?

Comment: proguard при сборке релиза уберет все лишнее (в том числе и из внешних библиотек)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться **Insptection**.

Если используете Android Studio то:

- нажимает <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>;
- в появившемся окне набираем `unused`;
- получаем подсказку в виде списка, такого плана:

[image: AndroidLint]

- выбираем интересующую нас `инспекцию`.

Comment: Как думаете, 100% безопасно?

Comment: @Omuradil ну как говорится, "волков бояться, в лес не ходить") да и не вижу повода сомневаться в безопасности данной штуки.

Comment: Тогда, спасибо огромное)!!! Попробую, отпишусь объязательно!

Comment: Попробовал, сколько раз не пробовал выскакивала сообщение "not find suspicious code". И поисках по этому сообщению, наткнулся на элементарный вариант) Во вкладке Analyze > Inspect Code, показывает весь список

Comment: Не знаю пока, сможет ли очистить... пробую...

Comment: @Omuradil да, Вы можете провести посредством `Analyze > Inspect Code` полную проверку проекта.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете провести посредством `Analyze > Inspect Code` полную проверку проекта.

**ermak0ff**